# Firebase implementation: "All com.android.support librairies must use the same version specification"

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to use Firebase on Android Studio. I have a problem in my grade file. I've got the following message on line

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1
```

> All com.android.support librairies must use the same version
>   specification. Found versions 27.1.0, 26.1.0

This is My Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.ilandes.inarttransport"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.3'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error disappear when I remove lines concerning Firebase

```
...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Firebase is the source of the conflict but how to fix that?

Comment: The best way is to implement Firebase using special tools in Android Studio itself.

Comment: That's what I do :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Comment: I read this post but it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding it

```
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Comment: that's doesn't work for me. Any way thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `./gradlew app:dependencies` to find the dependency tree and see which dependency is using the old version. Then check if this dependency itself has a new version.

Answer (score 0):

I had those lines of code at the end of my gradle file. It's removing the error but I don"t know if Firebase works fine, I need more tests...

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.0'
            }
        }

    }
}
```